# Resetting buttons java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, reset

I am creating a with a model-view-controller algorithm. If I have instances of a JButton defined in my controller class. For instance, I have: a button for reset, quit, undo, redo, and settings.

I have implemented their actionListeners. In my Controller class is where the actionPerformed() method is. I implement all 5 buttons. Right now the buttons are set as enabled. However, when the redo and undo are disabled and I push the reset button they stay disabled. How can I reset the state of the redo and undo buttons.

This is my GameController class specifically actionPerformed:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {
    if (e.getSource() instanceof DotButton) {
        try {
            undo.push((GameModel) gameModel.clone());
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException g) {
            g.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(gameModel.getNumberOfSteps()==0){
            int row = ((DotButton)(e.getSource())).getRow();
            int column = ((DotButton)(e.getSource())).getColumn();
            gameModel.capture(row,column);
            gameModel.step();
        }
        selectColor(((DotButton)(e.getSource())).getColor());
    } else if (e.getSource() instanceof JButton) {
        JButton clicked = (JButton)(e.getSource());

        if (clicked.getText().equals("Quit")) {
            /*try {
                serialization.serialize(gameModel, "savedGame.ser");
            } catch (IOException f) {
                f.printStackTrace();
            }*/
             System.exit(0);
         } else if (clicked.getText().equals("Reset")){
            reset();
            if (clicked.getText().equals("Redo")) {
                clicked.setEnabled(true);
            }
            if (clicked.getText().equals("Undo")) {
                clicked.setEnabled(true);
            }
         } else if (clicked.getText().equals("Redo")) {
            if (redo.isEmpty()) {
                clicked.setEnabled(false);
            }
            try {
                redo();
            } catch (CloneNotSupportedException g) {
                g.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
         else if (clicked.getText().equals("Undo")) {
            if (undo.isEmpty()) {
                clicked.setEnabled(false);
            }
            try {
                undo();
            } catch (CloneNotSupportedException g) {
                g.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
        else if (clicked.getText().equals("Settings")) {
            gameView.settingsMenu();
        }
    } else if (e.getSource() instanceof JRadioButton) {
        JRadioButton clickedR = (JRadioButton)(e.getSource());
        if (clickedR.getText().equals("Torus")) {
            setting1 = true;
        }
        if (clickedR.getText().equals("Diagonal")) {
            setting2 = true;
        }
    }
```

This is my GameView class creating the buttons:

```
public GameView(GameModel model, GameController gameController){
    super("Flood it -- the ITI 1121 version");

    this.gameModel = model;

    this.gameController = gameController;

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(gameModel.getSize(), gameModel.getSize()));
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 0, 20));
    board = new DotButton[gameModel.getSize()][gameModel.getSize()];

    for (int row = 0; row < gameModel.getSize(); row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < gameModel.getSize(); column++) {
            board[row][column] = new DotButton(row, column, gameModel.getColor(row,column), 
                (gameModel.getSize() < 26 ? DotButton.MEDIUM_SIZE : DotButton.SMALL_SIZE));
            board[row][column].addActionListener(gameController);
            panel.add(board[row][column]);
        }
    }

    add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    buttons = new JButton[5];
    buttons[0] = new JButton("Reset");
    buttons[1] = new JButton("Quit");
    buttons[2] = new JButton("Undo");
    buttons[3] = new JButton("Redo");
    buttons[4] = new JButton("Settings");
    for (JButton button : buttons) {
        button.setFocusPainted(false);
        button.addActionListener(gameController);
    }

    JPanel settingsPanel = new JPanel();
    settingsPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    settingsPanel.add(buttons[2]);
    settingsPanel.add(buttons[3]);
    settingsPanel.add(buttons[4]);

    JPanel control = new JPanel();
    control.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    scoreLabel = new JLabel();
    control.add(scoreLabel);
    control.add(buttons[0]);
    control.add(buttons[1]);


    add(settingsPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(control, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Should I create JButton instances in my GameController class as well as in the GameView.

Comment: For what's it's worth, I think your MVC is little skewed, the controller shouldn't care "how" the UI or model are implemented, only that that abide to a specific contract, that is, they generate certain events and provide access to certain data. Having said that, I would argue that the the correct place for the buttons and `ActionListener` is actually in the view. Unless it's imperative to the functionality of the contact between the controller and the view, the controller probably doesn't care when a button should be active or not, but the model does

Comment: To that end, the controller should be notified by the view when a state changes, the controller should notify the model and the model should then make some determination. It's probably also reasonable to consider that the model just doesn't care about that specific information, allowing the view more autonomy, but that would need to be decided on a use-by-use case

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible for this condition to ever be met

```
} else if (clicked.getText().equals("Reset")){
    reset();
    if (clicked.getText().equals("Redo")) {
```

If the first `if` statement is `true`, then the second can never be `true`